# Listar tarjetas de red activas en linux con C

Tags: c, lista

lo que me falta y no se realmente como hacerlo es listar que tarjetas de red estan activas, obtener los nombres(ejemplo: eth0,eth1), tengo un programa que ya me obtiene la mac y ocupa la validacion de la tarjeta eth0, pero mi duda es como listar todas las demas y saber si estan activas o no, les pongo el programa que tengo realizado, esta formado por:

Lic2.h

```
#ifndef _LIC2_H_
#define _LIC2_H_

#define LIC_OK                       0
#define LIC_NO_ADAPT_NAME_PROVIDED  -1
#define LIC_INVALID_ADAPTER         -2

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int licGetMacAddress(char * adapter, unsigned char mAddress[6]);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* LIC2_H_ */
```

Lic2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include "Lic2.h"

int licGetMacAddress(char * adapter, unsigned char mAddress[6]) {
int x, i;
int fd;
struct ifreq ifr;
char direcMac[20];

/* Initialices output variable */
memset(mAddress, 0, 6);

/* Validates adapter name */
if (!adapter)
  return LIC_NO_ADAPT_NAME_PROVIDED;
if (!strlen(adapter))
  return LIC_NO_ADAPT_NAME_PROVIDED;

/* Gets adapter's macaddress */
fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
ifr.ifr_addr.sa_family = AF_INET;
strncpy(ifr.ifr_name , adapter , IFNAMSIZ-1);
ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &ifr);
close(fd);
memcpy(mAddress, ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data, 6);

/* Verifies if adapter doesn't exist */
x = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
  if (!mAddress[i]) x++;
if (x == 6)
  return LIC_INVALID_ADAPTER;

return LIC_OK;
}
```

y el "Main" por asi llamarle

ejemplo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Lic2.h"

int main () {
int status, i;
unsigned char mAddress[6];

status=licGetMacAddress("eth0", mAddress);
if (status!=LIC_OK) {
  printf("Error al obtener el Mac Address: %d \n", status);
} else {
  printf("Mac Address: ");
  for (i=0; i<6; i++)
    printf("%02X", mAddress[i]);
  printf("\n");
}
return status;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes valerte de la lista de interfaces obtenida vía [getifaddrs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html).

La llamada te devuelve todas las interfaces, una vez por cada protocolo. Es decir, si eth0 tiene ipv4 e ipv6, aparecerá 2 veces en la lista. Si no te interesan duplicados, ya es tarea tuya procesarla para quedarte con una copia de cada uno.

La llamada también devuelve las interfaces inactivas, si te interesa solo las activas en el momento, quedate con las que tengan el flag `IFF_UP`

El siguiente código debiera imprimir todas las interfaces que tienen asignada una dirección:

```
struct ifaddrs *addrs,*tmp;

getifaddrs(&addrs);
tmp = addrs;

while (tmp)
{
    if (tmp->ifa_addr && tmp->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_PACKET)
        printf("%s\n", tmp->ifa_name);

    tmp = tmp->ifa_next;
}

freeifaddrs(addrs);
```

Comment: me sale error, a parte del codigo que pusiste debo de incluir algo mas ? y gracias por tu aportacion

Comment: bueno, sin saber que error te sale, es difícil adivinar. ¿leíste la documentación enlazada?

Comment: ok si corre el programa pero unicamente con la documentacion enlazada, como hago para añadir el codigo que pusiste al codigo de la documentaqcion y gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: ¿cuál es el mensaje de error? ¿es en tiempo de compilación? ¿en tiempo de corrida?

Comment: ya edite la pregunta, ya no tengo error solo que ahora es otra consulta ojala puedas ayudarme gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: @EdúArias, no edites la pregunta. Lo que debes hacer es realizar una nueva pregunta y en esa, si es de importancia, enlaza esta. Voy a revertir tu última edición para que esta quede como estaba.

Comment: Esto es importante porque acá no buscamos solamente ayudarte a ti con este problema, sino que utilizamos esto de pretexto para construir una base de datos de conocimiento para programadores que, con suerte, servirá de ahora en adelante a muchos otros que tengan una duda similar a la tuya.

Comment: ok disculpa lo que pasa es que soy nuevo en esta comunidad y la verdad no he leido las reglas, es mas aun no se en donde puedo encontrarlas para leerlas, pero de todas formas reitero mi agradecimiento a esta gran comunidad

Comment: Visita el [Centro de Ayuda](/help), allí encontrarás la información del funcionamiento y reglas, haz el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Bienvenido a SOes.